# Django 1.9, custom middleware + 404 error

Tags: python, django, middleware

I have written custom middleware which checks invites from users. The idea is to restrict the access to the website for users without invites. Everything is woking fine, except that users can see parts of the site when 404 or any other exception occurs and I don't want it.

I am using Django 1.9. In previous versions (as I remember) there was Exception middleware, but now I don't see it. I tried to put my middleware on the top of the stack but it doesn't help. What else can I do?

Lets say, I have following middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'myproject.middleware.InviteLoginForWebsiteMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
]
```

Here are my urls which redirect to handlers:

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^403/$', views.handler403, name="403"),
    url(r'^404/$', views.handler404, name="404"),
    url(r'^500/$', views.handler500, name="500"),

]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean, "users can see parts of the site when 404 occurs". That can only happen if you put part of the site in the 404 page.

Comment: I mean that my handlers redirect to the views which shows parts of the website interface. And I want to have middleware which totally restrict access to the interface.

Comment: You need to show some code.

Comment: ok, i will post it, but don't think the code will help a lot in such case

Comment: @RemcoGerlich yes, and I want the parts of the site to be shown when 404 error occurs in normal case, but not when user doesn't have invite for the whole website

Comment: So what does the middleware do? It should redirect to some page that doesn't have those parts.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I don't have problem with my custom middleware. It is working fine. When user goes to the index page it shows him custom login form and wait until he will input correct data. The only problem is if user tries to type something like mysite.com/blabla and this page does not exist. It redirects user to 404 handler which shows parts of the site interface. Probably a good question is how django handles 404 and other exceptions? If it is not happening in middleware then where?

Comment: Thank you for your time! I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the question by using process_request() rather then process_view() in my custom middleware. Thanks to all!